# Выплёскивание (overflow) текста из блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Друзья, всем привет! У меня такой вопрос: я верстаю макет, тут есть блок с постами блога. Правильным будет предусмотреть, чтоб при росте количества текста в посте верстка не ломалась. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильней это организовать? Я поставил блоку, который оборачивает тег

с текстом (первая картинка) overflow: hidden. Но тогда, если добавить текста, всё очень некрасиво смотрится. Чтобы это решить, можно этой обертке сделать высоту пониже, чтобы хвосты букв следующей строки не выглядывали (вторая картинка). Но ведь, наверное, необходимо как-то показать, что там ещё есть текст.
Надеюсь я четко изложил свою мысль: мне необходим способ избежать, так сказать, некрасивого выплёскивания текста из блока, которое может привести к тому что верстка сломается.

[[image]][1[image: ]]

Comment: [text-overflow: ellipsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) как раз для этого

Comment: @Grundy `text-overflow: ellipsis` работает только с одной неразрывной строкой текста. Если нужно укоротить абзац и поставить многоточие в последней строчке, для этого есть [`line-clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp)

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov или так ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Alexey Vladimirov, спасибо большое, помогли

Comment: @Константин https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/abpbedG вот так если текст многострочный

Comment: @Айболит, круто! спасибо большое, тоже думал о решении на js, но оно не было таким простым)

Answer (score -1):

попробуй, он ставит ... в конце

```
text-overflow: ellipsis
```